# Cannot get new value of control in popup modal

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Do web controls ever appear like you are changing their values but actually retain the previous value?

I created a pop-up modal for users to edit an item. When the user clicks edit on an item on the main page, the following sequence happens:

1. The item's ID is passed to the Page_Load event of the modal page, and is used to populate the page control's with the item's data.
2. The user changes a value in a control. Ex: Changes text in a TextBox contol.
3. The user clicks save, triggering the Click event which creates a DataTransferObject with the values in the textboxes, which will be stored.

However, on step 3, the control's new value (TextBox.Text) still holds the value that it orginially had, not the value the user put in.

Add.aspx:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="../MasterPages/Popup.Master" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDescription" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <telerik:RadButton ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Add.aspx.cs

```
//Cannot access the new values here
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //This will print the new text on Create, but the old text on Edit
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(TextBoxDescription.Text);
}

//works properly
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    objIDParam = Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["ObjectID"]);
    editMode = (objIDParam != 0) ? true : false;

    if(editMode)
        PopulateFields(objID);
}

//works properly
private void PopulateFields(long objID)
{
    MyObject obj = GetObjectByID(objID);
    TextBoxDescription.Text = obj.Description;
}
```

It is worth noting that this popup page is used for both creating items AND editing items. Create works fine (i.e. The item isn't saved with all blanks, but rather the user input). Editing an item will properly pull all that data back in, and let the user edit the fields, however I can't access the changed values in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for `IsPostBack` in the `Page_Load` method.

The `Page_Load` gets called before the `btnSave_Click` method, so the `TextBoxDescription.Text` is getting reset to `obj.Description` before the `btn_Save` method runs.

Try returning out of Page_Load if you're posting back:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
        return;

    objIDParam = Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["ObjectID"]);
    editMode = (objIDParam != 0) ? true : false;    

    if(editMode)
        PopulateFields(objID);
}
```

Have a look at [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Wow! I did not notice Page_Load was being called on btnSave_Click. I looked at the button's properties and AutoPostBack is set to 'true'. So is this page getting posted back BEFORE it has a chance to be closed by the javascript?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the telerik controls, but on a regular Button when the button is clicked, the page's state is posted back to the server. This will include the content of the TextBoxDescription textbox. The reason that it appears to be retaining its previous value is because the updated value is getting overwritten during the Page_Load method (when it calls PopulateFields), which runs before the btnSave method. ASP.NET knows whether this is the first load of the page, or a "Post Back" like when you've clicked a button. Generally you only want to populate fields on the initial load.

Comment: Got it. I assumed that if the button had an event handler (like Save) then it would do that rather than posting back and subsequently calling Page_Load. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: No problemo. Read up on the ASP.NET webforms page lifecycle... there are a lot of methods that run on every load and post back.